# Put floating controls on top of docking control in a container

Tags: c#, winforms

It easier to see my problem in below image. I need to fill the tabPage with a chart, and then put some buttons in the top left corner.

How may I do this programmatically? 
[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
        //UI
        tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();

        TabPage tp1 = new TabPage("tp1");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp1);

        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Text = "OK";
        btn1.Parent = tp1;

        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.Text = "OK2";
        btn2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 50);
        //btn2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        //btn2.Margin = new Padding(200,3,3,3);
        btn2.Parent = tp1;

        Chart cht = new Chart();
        cht.Parent = tp1;
        cht.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: and what have u tried so far??

Comment: Add them to the tab container...

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it using a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Add them to the tabpage and use Anchors instead of docking!